# How to distinguish low entropy and high entropy with the information produced using shannon entropy

Tags: math, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, entropy

I calculated an entropy level of user's behaviour for its possible states of occurence (H:=Home, w:=Work or E:=Elsewhere) for a day. Say a user A has its possible states for each hour of a day as {H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,W,E,E,H,H,H,H}

P(H)=13/24=0.54

P(W)=9/24=0.38

P(E)=2/24=0.08

Using shannon's entropy, I wanted to calculate the entropy level of a user to figure out how predictable the user is.

H(A)=(-P(H)*log2(H)) + (-P(W)*log2(W)) + (-P(E)*log2(E))

```
=0.48 + 0.53 + 0.29

=1.3
```

How to distinguish this information in bits as low entropy or high entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maximum entropy is achieved when all events are equally probable, and thus the outcome has highest uncertainty

[image]

In your case maximum entropy is:

```
Hn = log2(24) = 4.5849625007
```

The minimum is 0. It is up to you to decide if the result can be classified as *high* or *low* entropy.

Comment: Hi Lizusek, Thanks for your reply but actually I am confused a bit. I believe if I calculate entropy level for other users (Say, B, C, D) for each hour of the day then they will also have same entropy level. In this case, how will u classify which user is highly predictable and which one is not. I am trying to know if there is some sort of scale to measure so that if a user is over particular entropy level then its high uncertainty or not.

Comment: @Sunny you have to classify a user as a set of 24 values, just as you did in example case, and then each user has different probabilities of H, W, E and different entropy -> you can compare users based on entropy level

Comment: @Sunny can I explain more to you?

Comment: ,I would really appreciate it if you could explain bit more actually.What I'm really trying to do with entropy is to find the predictability level of different users for a period of one month (say JAN with 31 days).I tried to calculate the maximum entropy level for this and am confused if it is going to be log2 (24*31) OR log2 (24) =4.584 * 31.

Comment: The paper [here](http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/pdfs/realitymining_old.pdf)(pg. 259) shows that a user with low entropy is 30.9 and high entropy is 48.5. I am wondering how that has been distinguished. And the maximum entropy, we'll calculate is complete huge range for me to decide how to classify particular user as high or low entropic user. Thanks

Comment: The choice was made arbitrarily. You can count entropy values for a sample of observations (more is better). Calculate average and standard deviation, or maybe [quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) and use this as a scale.